# Remote EJB method parameters

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a problem in calling from ear application a remote EJB method in a separate ejb module with object parameters (Object of class `SolverConfig` defined in the remote EJB ) given that i made the class `SolverConfig` implements serializable interface and i always get the following exception:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException
```

So what do i need to do for the class `SolverConfig` in order to pass object of it as a parameter.
I noticed also that i cant even return String array from remote ejb method, where is the problem?

Comment: ALWAYS paste the full stack trace of an exception when asking about it.

Comment: Mabye SolverConfig contains some attributes which are not serializable.